# How do I select a css element with a text not attached to the attribute?

Tags: css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

I am currently working on Eclipse using java bindings and i'm automating an e-commerce website. I am using Selenium 2 (Webdriver) to write my automation scripts and I'm having an issue trying to get a particular element via css. My preference is css because of the unstable nature of xpath (especially with the changes implemented on our site weekly). Can anyone please assist me? Thanks in advance. There are two buttons i need to click and are both similar. The first one is the continue button:

```
<td class="content" style="vertical-align: bottom; ; background: url(http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/digital/video/avod-1-5/dp-sprite-total._V156422041_.png) no-repeat -3px -153px; padding: 0px 4px 0px 11px;">       Yes, continue with my purchase     </td>
```

The second one is the cancel button:

```
<td class="content" style="vertical-align: bottom; ; background: url(http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/digital/video/avod-1-5/dp-sprite-total._V156422041_.png) no-repeat -3px -181px; padding: 0px 4px 0px 11px;"> Cancel </td>
```

As you can see, they both have similar structures but only differ on the text. Now i can go as far as using this - `css=td.content`

but this brings both elements up and the script fails. What i need to do is input something that would use the text. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: sorry, i did write the full java code initially but then took it off. Just like I didn't include the webdriver code even though i tagged it selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS selectors don't work this way.  There was something called :[contains](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors)() but it was dropped.  You could add a second class to each `td` element like this:

```
<td class="content action_yes"...>
<td class="content action_no"...>
```

Then your CSS selector would look like this (in jQuery only because it's so clean, this approach is standard CSS)

```
$('.action_yes')
$('.action_no')
```

Comment: So in this case, I have to use xpath?

Comment: That would work or you could add a second class to each td.  It won't effect the style (as long as you don't associate CSS to that class) and it will make the intention of each td element cleaner.

Comment: Funnily enough, jQuery supports `:contains()`, and so does Selenium RC, but not WebDriver.

Comment: Thanks for the comment guys. I ended up using xpath to find the element as opposed to css or adding a second class to the td element.